# Can I get VS2012 standard library in VS2010

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, c++11, visual-studio-2012

Can I get VS 2012 standard library in VS 2010?

VS 2012  has such good things from C++11 as threading.
I think that installing VS2012 redist and replacing the contents of include and lib folders with VS2012 one will be enough.

Has anyone done this?

Comment: I don't think the cl.exe supplied with VS2010 will be able to compile the VS2012 lib. Why would you even want to do that? Why not just use VS2012?

Comment: Because I would have to reinstall it because it is beta now, not release.

Comment: And you don't think that you'd have to redo all this hacky work for the release library? It is almost guaranteed to change between beta and release.

Comment: When vs2012 will be release, I will install it.
Beta is beta, and I can't update beta to release by installing an update, I will have to fully reinstall, it is a long process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Reasons: ABI, Standards conformance and compiler hacks necessary to compile the libraries, etc...

A different redistributable will not get you the development files. Renaming the DLL's in them might get you the new library at runtime, but it will most likely crash and burn if you try to do that.

---

It seems I did not make myself clear enough: **DO NOT DO THIS!!** It will not work, and if it seems to work, you either didn't use anything worth the hassle or you're relying on a walking time bomb. Not to mention licensing issues.

Comment: VS2012 redist won't give me the lib and include files, but we can take them from VS 2012. The lib files are lib files. All the implementation (except templates) is in the dll files, dll files were compiled with VS2012, we will only will link our binary with them. Templates... I hope that their the code hadn't changed so much to make VS2010 not to build that code.